# Why does FSharpList have no GetEnumerator method?

Tags: c#, f#

I am trying to use FSharpList in C# for implementation purposes.
It says that it implements `IEnumerable` interface, but when I create an instance of it, it has no `GetEnumerator` function!

Comment: Maybe the interface is explicitly implemented, so you won't see the method on the class. But if you cast it to `IEnumerable`, you should be able to use it.

Comment: By the way, it's a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and as such very different from C#'s "`List<T>`" which is really just an array that will resize itself if necessary. As a linked list, it consists of two "components": A `Head` giving the first item in the list, and a `Tail` giving another `FSharpList<T>` containing the rest of the elements. See [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370372.aspx).

Comment: @carlosfigueira Hm... sorry I don't get it. How can it be not implemented by when you cast it, it becomes implemented? :-( P.S.: I'm a C# newbie, so excuse my ignorance!

Comment: @drozzy - [Explicitly implemented interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) are a .NET feature.  Languages like C# use them fairly rarely (although one extremely common occurrence is where `IEnumerable<T>` is implemented implicitly but the non-generic `IEnumerable` is implemented explicitly).  In F#, all interfaces are implemented explicitly, which is more unusual for a .NET language.

Comment: @kvb OOOH, now I get it. So I guess it's not really "casting" as much as gently guiding to which implementation to use. Thanks.

Comment: @drozzy - No, it is casting.  It's just an unintuitive feature: private methods can be used to implement an interface (and those methods don't even need to have the same name as the interface methods).  The only way for other code to call those methods is to upcast an instance of the class to the interface it implements and call the interface method.

Comment: @kvb I see. But from what I goggled, upcasting seems to be much less of a performance concern then regular, downcasting.

Comment: @drozzy - Yes, that should generally be the case.  The one exception would be for value types, where upcasting is not representation preserving  (in fact, at the IL level no cast needs to be performed at all for reference types).  In general, though, it would be extremely rare for this to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @kvb explicit implemented members are public not private

Comment: @RuneFS - what makes you say that?  At the IL level they are (can be?) private, AFAIK.

Comment: @kvb it is public in the sense that you can always access it (Might require a cast depending on compile time type of the identifier). There's no private inheritance in C# and since interface members are all public you can't limit the accessibility of the members when you implement the interface. That would remove type safety from interfaces. ANy method that took an interface as argument could fail because one of the methods were hidden away

Comment: @RuneFS - Sure, the method is callable through the interface.  However, it's not public (it cannot be called directly) - like I said, this is a weird and somewhat unintuitive feature.

Comment: @kvb the specifications agree with both of us. They are not public in the sense that they can't be called from the concrete type but that they are public in the sense that they are accessible from the object (which is what I've stated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does but you need to cast it to IEnumerable or use it in a foreach. It's explicitly define and hence won't show up in intellisense unless the declared type is IEnumerable

**EDIT**
From the comments I realized that the above could be read differently than expected.

Explicit implementations of interface methods is basically part of a disambiguation mechanism.
If a type implements two interfaces with one or more methods with the same signature (ignoring return type) you need to be able to distinguish between them.

The first part is to explictly implement one or both of them. For `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` that would be similar to the below code

```
object IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(){...}
T IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator(){...}
```

The second part of the disambiguation is at the call site. Even though both methods are part of the runtime type of the object you can't call it using regular call syntax. You need to tell the compile the compile time type that defined the method otherwise the compiler wouldn't know which of the methods to call.

So to call the above two methods you'd need code like the below

```
((IEnumerable)obj).GetEnumerator();
((IEnumerable<T>)obj).GetEnumerator();
```

or you could leave it to language constructs to cast for you (in which case the language specification would tell you which version that would be called

```
foreach(var item in obj) {
}
```

So even though the methods are actually part of the type of the object you need to help the compiler at compile time and tell the compiler which type that defined the particular method you wish to call.

Explicit implementations can of course be used without any ambiguities.

Comment: It's not just that intellisense won't show it; it's not valid code and won't compile unless you cast it to the interface type.  Remember to separate the language from the IDE.

Comment: @servy Where did I state that the IDE is the language? But casting is _not_ required since it will work in a foreach without

Comment: It works in a `foreach` because a `foreach` performs an explicit cast internally.  You didn't say the IDE is the language, but you implied it by discussing intellisense.  Intellisense merely helps you, as a coder, see what the actual language will or won't let you do.  If you typed out `GetEnumerator` on the type it still wouldn't work; so it's not that intellisense doesn't show it, that's merely a side effect of the fact that it's simply not a valid member of the actual type (unless you cast it).

Comment: @Servy This boggles my mind guys, how can something be not a member of the type until you cast it, especially if the interface it _implements_ says that it should be there? In my experience whenever I implement an interface, my code won't compile until I implement every single method of it!

Comment: @servy Well I never _tried_ to imply it. But since OP thought that the method was not part of the type I guess at the source of the confusion.
don't confuse language constructs with types the method is certainly part of the objects type. The call syntax is different but from a type theory perspective it certainly is part of the type of the object. Otherwise the cast wouldn't be a csat but a conversion which it is not